# How do I find $C^1$ mapping with given range

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a following question.

Find a one-to-one $C^1$ mapping $f$ from the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane to the first quadrant of the $uv$-plane such that the region where $x^2 \leq y \leq 2x^2$ and $1 \leq xy \leq 3$ is mapped to a rectangle. Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: what is the $uv$-plane?

Comment: @user159517 My textbook explains the transformation of coordinate system using two planes, one for the domain, and the other for the image. The uv-plane was named and used for the image plane.